# Insert 1 value in 2d array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need some help with my code. I try to insert only one value in each array. I need to fill in the row first and after that, if the row is full then move to the next column. I try to solve this part for a couple of days but I fail. So here is my code

```
const testData = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];                
const create2dArray = (row, column) => {
                    var result = [];
                    for(let i = 0; i< row; i++){
                        result[i]= [];
                        for(let j = 0; j<column; j++){   
                            result[i][j] = [];
                            for(let e = 0; e < testData.length; e++){
                            result[i][j] = [testData[e]];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return result;
            
                }
            let Column = 5
            let Row = 5
            filterQuotaData(EnrollmentQuota);
            var ground = create2dArray(Column,Row);
            console.log(ground);
```

Suppose the output is :

```
[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]
[6],[7],[8],[9],[]
[],[],[],[],[]
[],[],[],[],[]
[],[],[],[],[]
```

instead, I got:

```
[9],[9],[9],[9],[9]
[9],[9],[9],[9],[9]
[9],[9],[9],[9],[9]
[9],[9],[9],[9],[9]
[9],[9],[9],[9],[9]
```

I hope someone can help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening in your code is that you have the 3rd loop adding everything to each column from 2nd loop. The reason why they are all 9s is because you are overwriting each column by using an assignment instead of adding it to the array:

```
// 3rd loop
array[0][0][0] = 1 // 1st iteration [[[1],...]]
array[0][0][1] = 2 // 2nd iteration [[[2],...]]
```

Here's an example that uses 2 loops and pushes sub-arrays and shifts from test array.

```js
const test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const create2dArray = (row, column) => {
  let result = [];
  for (let r = 0; r < row; r++) {
    result.push([]);
    for (let c = 0; c < column; c++) {
      let data = test.length < 1 ? [] : [test.shift()]
      result[r].push(data);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
let row = 5, col = 5;

let ground = create2dArray(row, col);
console.log(JSON.stringify(ground));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate it. Good explanation, really helps me to understand my issues with my code. Have a great day man

Answer (score 1):

Following code

```js
const testData = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];                
const create2dArray = (row, column) => {
                    var result = [];
                    k = 0
                    for(let i = 0; i< row; i++){
                        result[i]= [];
                        for(let j = 0; j<column; j++){   
                            if(k < testData.length) {
                              result[i][j] = [testData[k]];
                            } else {
                              result[i][j] = [];
                            }
                            k++
                        }
                    }
                    return result;
            
                }
            let Column = 5
            let Row = 5
            //filterQuotaData(EnrollmentQuota);
            var ground = create2dArray(Column,Row);
            console.log(ground);
```

produces

```
[
  [ [ 1 ], [ 2 ], [ 3 ], [ 4 ], [ 5 ] ],
  [ [ 6 ], [ 7 ], [ 8 ], [ 9 ], [] ],
  [ [], [], [], [], [] ],
  [ [], [], [], [], [] ],
  [ [], [], [], [], [] ]
]
```

Does it what you need?

Comment: You can improve a bit this answer by replacing the "k" length check with this shorter syntax: 
const data = testData[k]; 
result[i][j] = data ? [data] : [];

Comment: yes, that is what I want to do, thank you solve my problem, I really appreciate it

Comment: How to random the output in the array?

Comment: Do you mean the put values of `testData` in random order in the output? Or generate random values in `testData`?